# Python ldap3 Reader return only one value

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, ldap3

I am trying to use Python ldap3 to retrieve users from a ldap.
This is my setup

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ObjectDef, AttrDef, Reader, Writer, ALL
server = Server('ldap://ldapserver:389', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, 'eTGlobalUserName=user,eTGlobalUserContainerName=Global Users,eTNamespaceName=CommonObjects,dc=iam,dc=eta', 'pass123', auto_bind=True)
```

When i search using the connection object, i can retrieve all users:

```py
conn.search('eTGlobalUserContainerName=Global Users,eTNamespaceName=CommonObjects,dc=iam,dc=eta', '(objectclass=eTGlobalUser)')
```

But when i try to get all users with the Reader i only get one item and it does not even contain an user, this is what i did:

```py
obj_person = ObjectDef('eTGlobalUser',conn)
r = Reader(conn,obj_person,'eTGlobalUserContainerName=Global Users,eTNamespaceName=CommonObjects,dc=iam,dc=eta')
r.search()
```

Is there anything i am missing?

**Edit 1**
This is the output of print(r):

```py
This is the output of print(r):
CURSOR : Reader
CONN   : ldap://ldapserver:389 - cleartext - user: eTGlobalUserName=user,eTGlobalUserContainerName=Global Users,eTNamespaceName=CommonObjects,dc=asusisv-iam,dc=eta - not 
lazy - bound - open - <local: 10.150.8.169:54196 - remote: 10.145.10.123:389> - tls not started - listening - SyncStrategy - internal decoder
DEFS   : eTGlobalUser
ATTRS  : ['eTAccessControlList', ... , 'eTGlobalUserName', ... , 'objectClass']
BASE   : 'eTGlobalUserContainerName=Global Users,eTNamespaceName=CommonObjects,dc=iam,dc=eta' [SUB]
FILTER : '(objectClass=eTGlobalUser)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access results with [`r.entries`](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/tutorial_abstraction_reader.html#matching-entries-in-cursor-results)

> Once a Reader cursor is populated with entries, you can get a specific
>   entry with the standard index feature of List object.

The Cursor object also has a shortcut : use `r[0]`, `r[1]` and so on to perform the same operation. For example :

```
for entry in r.entries:
    print(entry.entry_dn) 
    print(entry.<attribute_name>)

# or
for entry in r:
    ...
```

If you get 0 entries, you can just `print(r)` to see how is built the reader cursor and check if `CONN`, `BASE` and `FILTER` (that are used to build `r.search() queries`) are correctly converted from the parameters you give in `ObjectDef()` and `Reader()`.

Comment: @JoséCousiño It seems correct to me compared to `conn.search()` parameters, except maybe for the case (?) so after calling `r.search()` you should have `r.entries` populated. I don't know why this is not happening.. Nothing in the logs ?